# Woocommerce tour kit option/edit?

Tags: woocommerce

I noticed this popup when trying to add a product to Woocommerce.

**Feeling stuck?
You have been working on this product for a few minutes now.
Is there something you're struggling with? Share your feedback.**

I can't seem to find any options or settings to edit this or identify a plugin this is associated with.

Does anybody know where this code is or options to change it? I can't seem to locate it and Google only shows "Booking" results.[image]

Please see screenshot

Comment: This is part of woocommerce-admin bundled into woocommerce, this can be found in woocommerce/assets/client/admin/app/index.js